# how to only load one IFRAME using @media and display:none; CSS

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, media, hidden

I am using @media CSS to serve up 3 different sizes pages depending on device viewport width.

I use 3 's so depending on screen width I hide 2 and display 1

the problem is that when I use 's it loads all 3 even when the iframe is within display:none;

I need only one of the 's to load mainly the one in the  that is visible not the other two that are hidden.

here is an example of the html

```
<div class='s1'>
<p>Full size page content here</p>
<iframe id='frame1' src="chat/flashchat.php" width="513" height="500">     </iframe>
<p> more full size page content here</p>

</div>

<div class='s2'>
<p>Medium size page content here</p>
<iframe id='frame1' src="chat/flashchat.php" width="513" height="500">    </iframe>
<p>More medium content here</p>


</div>

<div class='s3'>
<p>Small page content here</p>
<iframe id='frame1' src="chat/flashchat.php" width="320" height="500">    </iframe>
<p>More small page content here</p>

</div>
```

here is the CSS:

```
@media handheld, screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.s2 {
display: none;
}
.s3 {
display: none;
}
.s1 {
display: block;
}

}

@media handheld, screen and (max-width:767px) and (min-width:513px) {
.s1 {
display: none;
}
.s3 {
display: none;
}
.s2 {
display: block;
}

}


@media handheld, screen and (max-width:512px)  {
.s1 {
display: none;
}
.s2 {
display: none;
}
.s3 {
display: block;
}


}
```

I am thinking javascript might provide a solution but would like to avoid that method if possible. I can only allow one of these IFRAMES to load even though only one is displayed the 3 loading messes up an automatic login feature because the  is actually loading 3 times even though it is hidden.

Any advise on resolving this issue?

Comment: What is "'s"? e.g. "I use three 's"

Comment: Why load the iframe three times at all? Aren't they each showing the same content?

Comment: I had this issue and resorted to using javascript on load and resize to manually inspect the appropriate breakpoints and which iframe should load. Not ideal, but the only way I found to avoid loading all three at once

Comment: What you're trying to do is not a good way to try and manage different size viewports

Comment: @ajkochanowicz 3 <div>

Comment: @charmeleon would you happen to have the javascript?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz the entire html page is loaded with two hiddden div's problem is that even in hidden div the iframe loads I need it to not load in the hidden div's

Comment: @JoeSwindell I understand it is not ideal but I am modifying some very old designs and not able to do a complete overhaul of the sites at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the JS I used:

```
$(document).on('ready', responsiveVideo);
$(window).on('resize', responsiveVideo);
function responsiveVideo() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    // Let's make sure that the appropriate video is visible
    $('.video-class-selector').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('.js__video-hack')) {
            return;
        }
        var isResponsiveVideo = $(this).parent('.video_mobile_wrapped').length,
            BREAKPOINT = 768;

        // Replace visible iframes with a proper iframe with a valid src attribute
        var $original = $(this).find('iframe');
        if ((isResponsiveVideo && windowWidth < BREAKPOINT) || (!isResponsiveVideo && windowWidth >= BREAKPOINT)) {
            var $clone = $original.clone();

            $clone.attr('src', $clone.attr('data-src'));
            $original.replaceWith($clone);

            $(this).addClass('js__video-hack');
        }
    });
}
```

My markup for the iframe looks like this:

```
<div class="video-class-selector">
  <iframe data-src="..." ...></iframe>
</div>
```

The responsive one is wrapped in a div with class video_mobile_wrapped:

```
<div class='video_mobile_wrapped'>
    <div class="video-class-selector">
      <iframe data-src="..." ...></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```